# How to draw double headed arrow in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a double headed arrow/html element in my web page with some text in it. Basically an arrow like in shapes in MS Word.
Also, I want it to be clickable so that I can trigger any event on the click.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This is not the kind of question Stackoverflow is for. We're here for when you've searched around a little, found some info that helps you get started, but then you get stuck on code that you think should work, but doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Some double-headed arrow characters exist in UTF-8 if you don't want to draw it yourself in CSS :

- `U+2194` ↔
- `U+2195` ↕
- `U+21D4` ⇔
- `U+21D5` ⇕

[This page](http://www.key-shortcut.com/en/writing-systems/symbols/arrows.html) has a lot of them if you need more.

Comment: Yes...but they are just characters. I want a create a clickable element with text in it.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. Do you want to create an arrow with some text IN it ? If yes, I think the simplest way is to create an image of that.